# checkers/ draughts game ? can this work or am i on the wrong path

Tags: chess

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.Action;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class testout extends JFrame{ 
    public JLabel l1; 

    //declaring images
    ImageIcon a= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b1.png");
    ImageIcon b= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b2.png");
    ImageIcon c= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b3.png");
    ImageIcon d= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b4.png");
    ImageIcon e= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b5.png");
    ImageIcon f= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b6.png");
    ImageIcon g= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b7.png");
    ImageIcon h= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b8.png");
    ImageIcon i= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b9.png");
    ImageIcon j= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b10.png");
    ImageIcon k= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b11.png");
    ImageIcon l= new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b12.png");

    public testout(){ 
        super("Checkers v0.1 beta");//name of window 
        try{
            JFrame checkerboard = new JFrame(); 
            checkerboard.setSize(400, 400);
            checkerboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
            checkerboard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            checkerboard.setResizable(false); 

            JLabel b1= new JLabel();
            b1.setBackground(Color.black); 
            checkerboard.add(b1); 
            JLabel l1=new JLabel(); 
            l1.setIcon(a); //sets icon for label
            checkerboard.add(l1);

            //mouse event 
            JLabel b2=new JLabel(); 
            checkerboard.add(b2);
            b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
            JLabel l2=new JLabel();
            l2.setIcon(b); 
            checkerboard.add(l2); 

            JLabel b3=new JLabel();
            checkerboard.add(b3); 
            b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
            JLabel l3=new JLabel(); 
            l3.setIcon(c); 
            checkerboard.add(l3); 

            JLabel b4=new JLabel(); 
            checkerboard.add(b4); 
            b4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JLabel l4=new JLabel(); 
            l4.setIcon(d); 
            checkerboard.add(l4);

            JLabel l5=new JLabel(); 
            l5.setIcon(e); 
            checkerboard.add(l5); 
            JLabel b5=new JLabel(); 
            checkerboard.add(b5); 
            b5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l6=new JLabel(); 
            l6.setIcon(f); 
            checkerboard.add(l6); 
            JLabel b6=new JLabel(); 
            checkerboard.add(b6);
            b6.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 

            JLabel l7=new JLabel();
            l7.setIcon(g); 
            checkerboard.add(l7); 
            JLabel b7=new JLabel();
            checkerboard.add(b7); 
            b7.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 

            JLabel l8=new
            JLabel(); l8.setIcon(h); checkerboard.add(l8); JLabel b8=new
            JLabel(); checkerboard.add(b8); b8.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel b9= new JLabel(); checkerboard.add(b9);
            b9.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel l9=new JLabel();
            l9.setIcon(i); checkerboard.add(l9); 

            JLabel b10=new JLabel();
            checkerboard.add(b10); b10.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel
            l10=new JLabel(); l10.setIcon(j); checkerboard.add(l10); JLabel

            b11=new JLabel(); checkerboard.add(b11);
            b11.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel l11=new JLabel();
            l11.setIcon(k); checkerboard.add(l11); 

            JLabel b12=new JLabel();
            checkerboard.add(b12); b12.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel
            l12=new JLabel(); l12.setIcon(l); checkerboard.add(l12); 

            JLabel
            l13=new JLabel("13"); checkerboard.add(l13); JLabel b13=new
            JLabel("13"); checkerboard.add(b13); b13.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l14=new JLabel("14"); checkerboard.add(l14); JLabel b14=new
            JLabel("14"); checkerboard.add(b14); b14.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l15=new JLabel("15"); checkerboard.add(l15); JLabel b15=new
            JLabel("15"); checkerboard.add(b15); b15.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l16=new JLabel("16"); checkerboard.add(l16); JLabel b16= new
            JLabel("16"); checkerboard.add(b16); b16.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel b17=new JLabel("17"); checkerboard.add(b17);
            b17.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel l17=new JLabel("17");
            checkerboard.add(l17); 

            JLabel b18=new JLabel("18");
            checkerboard.add(b18); b18.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel
            l18=new JLabel("18"); checkerboard.add(l18); 

            JLabel b19=new
            JLabel("19"); checkerboard.add(b19); b19.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JLabel l19=new JLabel("19"); checkerboard.add(l19); 

            JLabel b20=new
            JLabel("20"); checkerboard.add(b20); b20.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JLabel l20=new JLabel("20"); checkerboard.add(l20); 

            JLabel l21=new
            JLabel("21"); checkerboard.add(l21); JLabel b21=new JLabel("21");
            checkerboard.add(b21); b21.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 

            JLabel
            l22=new JLabel("22"); checkerboard.add(l22); JLabel b22=new
            JLabel("22"); checkerboard.add(b22); b22.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l23=new JLabel("23"); checkerboard.add(l23); JLabel b23= new
            JLabel("23"); checkerboard.add(b23); b23.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l24=new JLabel("24"); checkerboard.add(l24); JLabel b24=new
            JLabel("24"); checkerboard.add(b24); b24.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel b25=new JLabel("25"); checkerboard.add(b25);
            b25.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel l25=new JLabel("25");
            checkerboard.add(l25); 

            JLabel b26=new JLabel("26");
            checkerboard.add(b26); b26.setBackground(Color.BLACK); JLabel
            l26=new JLabel("26"); checkerboard.add(l26); 

            JLabel b27=new
            JLabel("27"); b27.setBackground(Color.BLACK); checkerboard.add(b27);
            JLabel l27=new JLabel("27"); checkerboard.add(l27); 

            JLabel b28=new
            JLabel("28"); checkerboard.add(b28); b28.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            JLabel l28=new JLabel("28"); checkerboard.add(l28); 

            JLabel l29=new
            JLabel("29"); checkerboard.add(l29); JLabel b29=new JLabel("29");
            checkerboard.add(b29); b29.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 

            JLabel
            l30=new JLabel("30"); checkerboard.add(l30); JLabel b30= new
            JLabel("30"); checkerboard.add(b30); b30.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l31=new JLabel("31"); checkerboard.add(l31); JLabel b31=new
            JLabel("31"); checkerboard.add(b31); b31.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            JLabel l32=new JLabel("32"); checkerboard.add(l32); JLabel b32=new
            JLabel("32"); checkerboard.add(b32); b32.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            checkerboard.setVisible(true); //event handlers 
            moves move=new moves(); //listener 
            l1.addMouseListener(move);
            l1.addMouseMotionListener(move); 
            l12.addMouseMotionListener(move);
            l12.addMouseListener(move); 
        } catch(Exception w){ } 
    } 

    public class moves implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{ 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent z){
            if(l1.contains(z.getX(),z.getY()))updateLocation(z); 
        } 

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent z){ } 
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent z){ updateLocation(z); } 
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent z){ }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent z){} 
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent z){} 
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent z){ }
        public void updateLocation(MouseEvent z){ 
            l1.setLocation(z.getX(), z.getY()); 
            if(l1.contains(z.getX(),z.getY())) { 
            } else {
            } 
            repaint(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code so it's readable. Nobody is going to peruse _that_.

Comment: I'd say that you are on the wrong track for this post. Please fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the most important programming principle for you to learn is *Don't Repeat Yourself* (DRY).  Notice how repetitive your code is.

In the first block, you declare 12 variables (named a, b, c, etc.), that only vary on the member names and the file names.  You should replace repeated data structures with collections like arrays and repeated code with loops.  For example:

```
private ImageIcon[] icons;

// Then, in your constructor
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    icons[i] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\wamae\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\checkers\\src\\checkers\\b" + (i + 1).toString() + ".png");
}
```

Notice how 12 lines of code can be replaced with 4.  Consider replacing the rest of your repetitive code and data with loops and collections.  Otherwise, you may find the code too big to manage and too time-intensive to change.